# Python - print "x" "y" times when passed in a list of [x,y]

Tags: python, list

python n00b here doing the pythonchallenge, stuck on middle of a level right now.

ex: ([' ', 10], ['#', 20])

How do I print space 10 times with python? I've tried many things, but none worked...

Thanks!

edit: I'm not looking to learn how to use for-loops, but rather, list-manipulation(is that what they're called?) techniques that i can use to print a list with *any* value as the first element.... thanks for the replies though!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
print ' ' * 10
```

Same as you would for any other character, e.g.

```
print 'a' * 10
```

So for your list, assuming it's called `l`:

```
for c, n in l:
    print c * n
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! but is there a way so it will print whatever is in the first array?

Comment: Yes, using a `for` loop.  I added an example.

Comment: Hey! that is exactly what i was looking for! i did something like [c, n] = l, but didn't work.... thanks!

Comment: `for [c, n] in l:` should work too, provided it's written as a for loop.  See "list unpacking" and "tuple unpacking" at http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can multiply a string by an integer to get a repeated version of the string:

```
>>> mystring = ' ' * 10
>>> mystring
'          '
```

Obviously, you can print the result of the expression directly:

```
>>> print '#' * 20
####################
```

This also works for tuples and lists:

```
>>> (1,2,3) * 2
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
>>> ['a','b','c'] * 3
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on **for loop** in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html), it will do what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ' ' * 10
```

You may not see it, because it is space.